# exporting xtrace/BASH_XTRACEFD but xtrace output going to stderr, not custom filedescriptor

Tags: bash, debugging, file-descriptor

I'm trying to get a shell script executed by a harness to use the harness' BASH_XTRACEFD.  Here's a trimmed down version of what I'm attempting that shows the issue.  I want '+ echo foobar' in /tmp/xtrace and don't want to reference /tmp/xtrace in /tmp/subject.

```
[bash]$ cat /tmp/harness
#!/bin/bash
exec 6> /tmp/xtrace
export BASH_XTRACEFD=6
set -o xtrace
export SHELLOPTS
/tmp/subject
set +o xtrace
[bash]$ cat /tmp/subject
#!/bin/bash
echo foobar
echo $SHELLOPTS
echo $BASH_XTRACEFD
ls -l /dev/fd/$BASH_XTRACEFD
[bash]$ /tmp/harness
+ echo foobar
foobar
+ echo braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:xtrace
braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:xtrace
+ echo 6
6
+ ls -l /dev/fd/6
l-wx------ 1 build build 64 Nov 29 12:15 /dev/fd/6 -> /tmp/xtrace
[bash]$ cat /tmp/xtrace 
+ export SHELLOPTS
+ /tmp/subject
+ set +o xtrace
[bash]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in bash 4.1.x.

From the bash release [changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) (in the `bash-4.2-alpha` section):

> ee. Fixed a bug that caused bash to not change the xtrace file descriptor if
>       BASH_XTRACEFD was found in the shell environment at startup.

That said quick testing (with bash 4.1.2) indicates that you can just set `BASH_XTRACEFD` in the script itself for it to take effect (and it takes effect immediately).

So if you stick `BASH_XTRACEFD=$BASH_XTRACEFD` at the top of `/tmp/subject` you'll see its `xtrace` output in the file the way you want.